# return list with elements from list of lists

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list of lists like the input example below “testccffilt”.  I’m trying to return a list where I pick off the name from each list and the lag.  For example, for the first list it would be:

```
c(‘TimeToShip’,1)
```

I’ve tried the lapply example below, but it doesn’t give me exactly the output I’m looking for.  I have an example of the desired type of output I’m trying to get also below.  Any tips are very much appreciated.

input:

```
> testccffilt

$TimeToShip
           cor lag
3284 0.9998749   1

$TimeToRelease
           cor lag
3285 0.9997293   2
```

tried:

```
testlist<-lapply(testccffilt,function(x)list(names(x),x$lag))
```

testlist

```
$TimeToShip
$TimeToShip[[1]]
[1] "cor" "lag"

$TimeToShip[[2]]
[1] 1


$TimeToRelease
$TimeToRelease[[1]]
[1] "cor" "lag"

$TimeToRelease[[2]]
[1] 2
```

desired output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "TimeToShip" "1"         

[[2]]
[1] "TimeToRelease" "2"
```

## Data:

```
dput(testccffilt)
structure(list(TimeToShip = structure(list(cor = 0.999874880882358, 
    lag = 1), .Names = c("cor", "lag"), row.names = 3284L, class = "data.frame"), 
    TimeToRelease = structure(list(cor = 0.999729343078789, lag = 2), .Names = c("cor", 
    "lag"), row.names = 3285L, class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("TimeToShip", 
"TimeToRelease"))
```

Comment: @markus Thank you for getting back to me so quickly.  I added an update to the original post where I dput(testccffilt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option using a for loop

```
out <- vector(mode = "list", length(testccffilt))
for (i in 1:length(testccffilt)) {
  out[[i]] <- c(names(testccffilt)[[i]], testccffilt[[i]][["lag"]])
}
out
#[[1]]
#[1] "TimeToShip" "1"         

#[[2]]
#[1] "TimeToRelease" "2"
```

---

Another option is `lapply` which might be faster.

```
lapply(1:length(testccffilt), function(x)
  c(names(testccffilt)[[x]], testccffilt[[x]][["lag"]]))
```

Comment: Why not `lapply`?

Comment: @Masoud Like so: `lapply(1:length(testccffilt), function(x) c(names(testccffilt)[[x]], testccffilt[[x]][["lag"]]))` ?

Comment: exactly, isn't that faster?

Comment: @Masoud Dunno. I don't find it any easier to read so I decided in favor of the for loop. Was thinking about `Map` but could not get it working. Would you consider to include a benchmark?

Comment: tbh don't care that much. Just include `lapply` in your answer as well, OP will decide or will benchmark if computation cost is at stake. Cheers.

Comment: @markus Thank you, that worked nicely!  lists of lists give me such a headache.